# FPDF - Output in row wise with repeat count

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am trying to get output like below image **"Expected Output" column wise** but my current output is like below **"output" field wise**. trying in some ways but failed to get output what i am expecting. another issue is, i also want to repeat one output in 2,3... time based on repeat count column value.
any advice will be helpfull to complete work. thanks in advance.
[image]

```html
$row_height = 10;
$pdf->SetY(5);
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
$i = 0;
$max = 22;
$row_height = 10;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    if ($i == $max)
    {
        $pdf->AddPage();
  
        //print column titles for the current page
          
 }
 $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 7);
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis+1);
 $pdf->Cell(8, 5, $SL, 0, 0, 'C', 1);
 $pdf->SetY($y_axis+9);
 $pdf->Cell(40, 5, $Style, 0, 0, 'L', 1);
 $pdf->SetY($y_axis+15);
 $pdf->Cell(50, 5, $Code, 0, 0, 'L', 1);
 
 $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
   
   $i = $i + 1;  }
   
mysql_close($link);


   //$Supplier=$row('Supplier');
        $pdf->Output($PI_SL.'-'.$CUSTOMER_NAME.'.pdf','I');
```